# rewiring a 3 switch light switch

Tags: light, multiway-switch

Hi I have got a light switch at the bottom of the stairs with 3 switches on it. One to turn the stairs lights on, one to turn the outside light on and one that turns a light on at the bottom of the stairs. What I want to do it make the stairs lights and the one at the bottom of the stairs turn on with one switch instead of 2 separate switches. Can someone point me in the right direction with which wires I need to swap in the light switch please?

Comment: Presumably there is also a switch at the top of the stairs that also turns the stair lights on.

Comment: Please upload pictures showing all the wires attached to the switches. Are all 3 lights on the same breaker? Do any of the lights have a second switch (3-way switches)?